# How to pass the single columnar dependent variable to train the linear regression model?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am new to Machine learning and started course on Simple Linear Regression model recently.

I have a dataset where except for a column `id` (integer type), all the columns are of `String` datatype.
And I have loaded it into a pandas dataframe and selected indexes out of it as below.

The pandas dataframe has total 32 columns and the 33rd column is the dependent variable column that just says `YES` or `NO`.
Using all the independent variables (columns 0 to 31), I am trying to find if I can predict the values in column 32 which is my dependent variable.

```
data = psyco.read_into_pandas()
X = data.iloc[:, 1:33].values
Y = data.iloc[:, 32].values

# Add missing values
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent', add_indicator=True)

# Fit the rows and columns into the imputer
imputer.fit(X[:, 1:33])

# Transform the data.
X[:, 1:33] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:33])

# One hot encoding
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))

# Label Encoder
le = LabelEncoder()
Y = le.fit_transform(Y)

# Split data into train and test data
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

Before sending the values of `X_train` and `Y_train`, I just printed the values of `Y_train` and I can see that it contains an array of integers which could be seen in the image below.

[image]

But when I send the data of `X_train` and `Y_train` to my `LinearRegression()` I am facing an error that says:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'yes'
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Some/Path/mltask.py", line 52, in task_2
    lr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  File "/Some/Path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py", line 684, in fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(
  File "/Some/Path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 596, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "/Some/Path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 1074, in check_X_y
    X = check_array(
  File "/Some/Path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 856, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'yes'
```

What I don't understand is when I print `Y_train` I see integers in the array but the regression says it can't convert String to float.

Could anyone let me know if I missed any step in between and how can I correct my mistake ?
Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a small reproducible data sample to help out?

Answer (score 0):

I think your untransformed data might be in X_train, not Y_train.

Explanation :
You split your data the following way :

```py
X = data.iloc[:, 1:33].values
Y = data.iloc[:, 32].values
```

This means that `Y` is included in `X`. In python indices start at 0 so if your dependent variable is the last column, you want to split like this instead :

```py
X = data.iloc[:, 0:32].values
Y = data.iloc[:, 32]
```

Otherwise you will try to predict Y with Y being in the feature set which you would not need Linear Regression to achieve.

In the rest of your code the extra column in X is not passed through the `OneHotEncoder` (because you pass columns 1 to 31) which results in you having some "yes", "no" data in X_train